# Input range with increased clickable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am trying to code an input range with narrow tracker and small thumb, but with wider clickable area than tracker.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <input type="range" orient="vertical" class="volume-slider"/>
</div>
```

For example, I have a `div.slider-wrapper` wrapper for input range and when I click inside the wrapper, input value would change.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xo2dknn/)

I checked [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/) and [jquery ui slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical), but didn't find solution for this.

```css
.slider-wrapper{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    /*border: 1px solid white;*/

    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 80px;

    transform: rotate(270deg);

    position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: 37px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #61b4f7;
    border: none;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #61b4f7;
    border: none;
    /* border-radius: 3px; */
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    
    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;
    
    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #61b4f7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <input type="range" orient="vertical" class="volume-slider"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding padding to the range element will increase the clickable space. You can then put a transparent background on the element:

```css
.slider-wrapper{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

input[type=range] {
    padding: 19px 10px;
    background-color: transparent;

    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    /*border: 1px solid white;*/

    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 80px;

    transform: rotate(270deg);

    position: relative;
    left: -32px;
    top: 28px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #61b4f7;
    border: none;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #61b4f7;
    border: none;
    /* border-radius: 3px; */
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    
    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;
    
    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #61b4f7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #61b4f7;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <input type="range" orient="vertical" class="volume-slider"/>
</div>
```